# Update HTML key attribute from array index

Tags: javascript, html

I have simple html structure like this:

```
<ul>
    <li key="0">Text1</li>
    <li key="1">Text2</li>
    <li key="2">Text3</li>
</ul>
```

So every `li` has key attribute, which is index of array(of objects) element. And I wanna to delete `li` by its key. So I use splice for this:

```
let keyBook = getAttribute("key");
...
books.splice(keyBook, 1);
```

And after this key attributes of `li` elems are not actual. So my question is: how can I update my keys from array indexes after splice?

Comment: I don't think you've provided us with enough here. Your example should be complete *(you've provided all parts necessary to reproduce the problem)*, and verifiable *(the problem you are having is present in the example you've provided)*. Please review this for more information: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

build a component which knows how to render itself...

```js
class Keys {
  constructor(data, container) {
    this._data = [].concat(data)
    this.container = container;
    
    this.render();
  }
  
  remove(key) {
    this._data = this._data.filter(k => k !== key);
    
    return this.render();
  }
  
  add(key) {
    this._data = this._data.concat(key).sort();
    
    return this.render();
  }
  
  render() {
    this
      .container
      .innerHTML = this
        ._data
        .reduce((res, text, index) => (
          res.concat(`<li key="${index}">Text ${text}</li>`)
        ), '')
    ;
    
    return this;
  }
}

var cntr = document.getElementById('ListContainer');
var data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var keys = new Keys(data, cntr);

window.setTimeout(() => keys.remove(3), 2000);
window.setTimeout(() => keys.add(67), 3500);
```

```html
<ul id="ListContainer"></ul>
```

Comment: Yes I  use it to delete li, but problem is to update keys after it. For example: After deleting elem with key="1", I want to update keys from array. And the element with key="2" must be key="1"

Comment: but instead of complicating everything, you just need to re/render all the list again... it will be automatically bound to the correct keys.